# Github API delete event

Tags: github, github-api

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#deleteevent

Based on the above events, how can I discover if a repo has been deleted? I'm currently using the Github archives files (https://www.githubarchive.org/) to feed my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can't -- there's no event for that, so you'd need to try and fetch the repository with an API call. And you also can't know if it was really deleted or made private (except if you have access to the private repository, which you probably don't).